# How to access the scope present in the link function from the controller when both are in the same directive

Tags: angularjs

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.someList = [1,2,3,4]; 
},

controller:function($scope, $attrs){
    console.log($scope.someList); //gives undefined
}
```

How can I access the scope in the link function from the controller? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the order they are executed, the controller is executed first, and afterwards the link function is executed. You can try it by writing,

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    console.log(1);
},

controller:function($scope, $attrs){
    console.log(2);
}
```

The execution order should be 2 - 1. Well, what you could do instead, is something like this, the execution order is still the same, you can inject the controller to the link or share data between the scope, just know that the controller executes first and then the link.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So, is there any way I can make the link function execute first?

Comment: Not that I know of, and even if you could execute the link first, it would be bad pracise. Link is the last one to run since it is where you should have $watchers, create bind/eventlisteners, change the DOM etc.